# How to get how many days passed since start of this year?

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, select

I have a query which uses needs to know how many days passed since 1st of January in the current year.

Which means that if the query runs for example in:

> 2nd Jan 2017 than it should return 2 (as 2 days passed since 1st Jan
>   2017).
>
> 10th Feb 2016 than it should return 41 (as 41 days passed since 1st
>   Jan 2016).

basically it needs to take `Current Year` from `Curent Date` and count the days since `1/1/(Year).`

i have the current year with: `SELECT EXTRACT(year FROM CURRENT_DATE);`

I created the 1st of Jan with:

```
select (SELECT EXTRACT(year FROM CURRENT_DATE)::text || '-01-01')::date
```

How do I get the difference from this date to `Current_Date`?

Basically this question can be **Given two dates, how many days between them**?

Something like `age(timestamp '2016-01-01', timestamp '2016-06-15')` **isn't good** because I need the result only in days. while age gives in years,months and days.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An easier approach may be to extract the day of year ("doy") field from the date:

```
db=> SELECT EXTRACT(DOY FROM CURRENT_DATE);
 date_part 
-----------
        41
```

And if you need it as a number, you could just cast it:

```
db=> SELECT EXTRACT(DOY FROM CURRENT_DATE)::int;
 date_part 
-----------
        41
```

Note: The result 41 was produced by running the query today, February 9th.

Comment: @java: it's here http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT

Answer (score 1):

> *Given two dates, how many days between them*

Just [subtract one from the other](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html).

---

In your case you could just round the current_date to the start of the year and subtract that from the current date:

```
select current_date - date_trunc('year', current_date)::date
```

The `::date` cast is necessary to get the result as an integer, otherwise the result will be an interval.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to use **DATEDIFF**

```
 SELECT DATE_PART('day', now()::timestamp - '2016-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp);
```